# Как сделать зеркальную копию БД PostgreSQL?

Tags: база-данных, postgresql, vps

Есть пара серверов с БД на PostgreSQL 9.6.
Один сервер - локальный(для наибольшей скорости взаимодействия с БД), а второй - на VPS. Доступ к БД на VPS ведется через VPN, и скорость работы с удаленной БД кратно ниже, чем с локальной. Удаленный VPS также используется для наполнения БД(парсинг сайтов, мониторинг сервисов), чтобы не нагружать локальный(собственный) комп.
Стоит задача создания локальной копии БД, находящейся на VPS.

Как возможно реализовать, учитывая, что данные могут не только добавляться и изменяться, но и удаляться из БД на VPS? Ну и соответственно, чтобы ни одна из БД не останавливалась для переноса данных.

Comment: Ключевые слова: `Кластеризация PostgreSQL`.

Answer (score 0):

Тот же вопрос терзает и меня, разница в том, что вторая копия - не на VPS, а в удаленном филиале.

Как я понял, в наших случаях поможет только Bi-Directional Replication, то есть репликация с двумя "мастерами" - обе реплики будут читать и писать в базу, которая будет синхронизироваться и в идеале будет одинакова на обеих хостах.

[Ссылка на официальном сайте на документацию по Bi-Directional Replication](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/BDR_User_Guide)

Пока что присматриваюсь к этому проекту - [2ndQuadrant Postgres-BDR](https://www.2ndquadrant.com/en/resources/bdr/). Похоже, именно оно должно подойти для реализации двух реплик с записью и чтением в обеих.